# Differential Equation linear, separable, neither or both?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck on deciding whether or not the differential equation 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}$$ is linear or separable? I believe it is linear although I am confused on the value of $P(x)$ since $\frac{1}{y} < y$.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is $P(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

The standard form of a first order linear differential equation in $(y,x)$ is given as ,

$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)$.

Since your equation cannot be written as above equation.

So your equation is not linear in $(y,x)$.

Hence $P(x)$ does not exist.

As @the_candyman showed that it is not a separable too.

Answer (score 0):

For sure, it is not linear. Check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation) to understand the meaning of linearity. 
Moreover, it is not separable, since you can not rewrite it as:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = f(y)g(x).$$

In fact:

$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{x+y}{xy} \neq f(y)g(x).$$